# Cannot create an instance of a class from another namespace?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

Okay, so this is really werid. I've never encountered anything like this.

Part of my program (Fails to compile) contains three namespaces as following:

```
// namespaceA.h
namespace A {
enum Kind { jimmy, david };
}
// end of namespaceA.h

// namespaceB.h
#include "namespaceA.h"
namespace B {
class Tree {
    public:
    Tree *prev;
    Tree *next;
    Tree *down;
    A::Kind kind;

    Tree();
    ~Tree();
};
}
// end of namespaceB.h
// Implementation details of the class are placed in namespaceB.cc
// Constructor / Desctructor defined in the namespaceB.cc file!
// Something like this,
#include "namespaceB.h"
namespace B {
inline Tree::Tree() { ... }
inline Tree::~Tree() { ... }
}

// namespaceC.cc
#include "namespace.B"
namespace C {
void run() {
    B::Tree *tree;    // FINE
    B::Tree tree;     // Fail to compile!?
}
}
// end of namespaceC.cc
```

Now, g++ went along just fine but the linker ld complains:

```
 "namespaceC.cc: undefined reference to `B::Tree::Tree()'
 "namespaceC.cc: undefined reference to `B::Tree::~Tree()'
```

I have never ever encountered anything like this before... This just seems really weird, I don't even know any words/terms to describe this problem.

I would much appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: How do you try to link it? It seems like you have forgotten to link to the file where B is defined.

Comment: I compile the whole program in a rlly stupid way. I just "g++ -Wall *" it. Maybe that is a problem?

Comment: That should work. I recall having problems with inlined constructors, maybe you could try to remove the inline in front of B::Tree() and Tree::~Tree()

Comment: Yes! That did solve it! You guys on stackoverflow are so helpful! THANKS SO MUCH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definitions of `B::Tree::Tree()` and `B::Tree::~Tree()` are declared inline. This means they are only available in that source file, not any others.

Either removing `inline` from the definitions, or moving the inline definitions into a header file included by all source files that need them, should fix the link errors.

Comment: You sir are the man!!! Thank you sooo much. And here I thought inlining will improve the efficiency and such. I stayed up unti 4am this morning for this thing. MAN THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  namespaceC.cc: undefined reference to `B::Tree::Tree()'
>  namespaceC.cc: undefined reference to `B::Tree::~Tree()'
> ```

Those are ***not compiler errors***, they are ***linker errors***. The problem is that you ***declared*** the constructor and destructor, but never ***defined*** them. So the compiler finds the declarations and accepts them, but ***the linker cannot find the definitions*** to link the references to.

See ***[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/140719)*** for what is a declaration and what is a definition and what they are good/needed for.

Comment: I did define the contructor and destructor in namespaceB.cc file. I'll edit my question to be more clear about it

Comment: @BeyondSora: Then you either haven't compiled the namespacB.cc file or you don't pass the resulting object file to the linker. Because the error message unambiguously says the linker cannot find those definition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the constructor and destructor for `B::Tree` somewhere either inline or in *namespaceB.cc*.  By creating an instance of `B`, you are requiring the existence of the constructor and destructor.

Comment: Yes, I did just that in namespaceB.cc with something along the line of "inline Tree::Tree() {...} ..."

Answer (score 0):

The pointer compiles fine because all pointers are the same. It's just the semantics allowed for different object types differ.
It would have compiled find up until the point you tried to use it.
But to create an actual object, you need the actual definition.

To use definitions from another namespace, you either used scopes, or use **[using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**:

```
#include "namespace.B"
using namespace B;
namespace C {
void run() {
    Tree *tree;    // FINE
    Tree tree;     // Fail to compile!?
}
}
```

or:

```
   #include "namespace.B"
    namespace C {
    void run() {
        B::Tree *tree;    // FINE
        B::Tree tree;     // Fail to compile!?
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the Tree constructor & destructor, but you don't show us where you define them (you just say you implement Tree in namespaceB.cc)

Assuming you have defined them, you must ensure you are including both namespaceC.o *and* namespaceB.o on your link line.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a *namespace* problem, neither a compiler error. The compiler is happy, but linker fails to find the definition of `B::Tree::Tree()`. You need to supply the source file for implementation, or use `-c` flag to "just compile".

Answer (score 0):

First, you declared constructor and destructor of class `Tree` yourself so compiler didn't provide default implementation - you need to implement them yourself! (Or just remove those declarations...).

It is not enough to include headers but you need to explicitly say that you're using namespaces from those headers:

In `namespaceC.cc` add `using namespace B;` after you include `namespace.B` or, even better, prepend types with a namespace qualifier:

```
B::Tree *tree;    
B::Tree tree;
```

Comment: I'm sry, I did have the namespace in my actual program... I ll edit my questio now to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the codes in Visual studio 2005. If I remove the "inline" in namespaceB.cc for the constructor and destructor, it can link without errors.

Then I found this post: [G++ won't accept inline constructors in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267009/g-wont-accept-inline-constructors-in-c)

it says that for inline functions you must have its definition in every file that calls the function. So it is recommended to put inline definition in header file.