# Does Inline restrict the function/method to the scope of its current source file?

Tags: c++, inline

Say I have something the following in my program,

```
// namespaceB.h
#include "namespaceA.h"
namespace B {
class Tree {
    public:
    Tree *prev;
    Tree *next;
    Tree *down;
    A::Kind kind;

    Tree();
    ~Tree();
};
}
// end of namespaceB.h
// Implementation details of the class are placed in namespaceB.cc
// Constructor / Desctructor defined in the namespaceB.cc file!
// Something like this,
#include "namespaceB.h"
namespace B {
inline Tree::Tree() { ... }
inline Tree::~Tree() { ... }
}
```

My question is that does inlining the ctor/dtor restrict their uses to within the current source file?

I thought inlining is just a way to improve efficiency?

What if Tree has a memeber method like

```
Tree& Tree::operator+(Tree const& rhs);
```

defined in header file, and in the source file

```
inline Tree& Tree::operator+(Tree const& rhs) { ... }
```

I played with that a bit, and it seems "inline" here also restricts Tree::operator+(...) to the scope of that source file

which means this will fail:

```
#include "namespaceB.h"
int main() {
B::Tree tree;    // Fail to link
return 0;    
}
```

As shown here:
[Cannot create an instance of a class from another namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414605/cannot-create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-another-namespace)

After I removed "inline" from ctor/dtor of class Tree, everything compiled and linked perfectly.

Can someone please explain what exactly inline does?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark a function as inline, you must include it in every source file from which it is used.

The C++11 standard has this to say:

> 7.1.2/4: "An inline function shall be defined in every
>   translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the
>   same definition in every case."

Comment: Pff, you even dug the paragraph, I fold :)

Comment: Ah, and I just read somewhere that an inline function is not compiled as a separate unit but as part of the calling function, which seems to make sense to me (the whole purpose of inline).

Comment: @BeyondSora, exactly, and that's why your linked does not find it, so the effect is **as if** the scope was restricted